# Chrome has recently started chopping the bottom of some titles, anyone know why?

Tags: css, google-chrome, heading, bugs

The title is the entirety really.

Chrome has started to chop the bottom off my titles (not noticed in on any paragraph text).
I've tried the usual, incognito mode to disable and extensions, delete my user in settings.

This is happening on a few of my sites, on different hosts.

Not repeatable in other browsers.

Has anyone come across this before?

[image: Image showing the issue.]

Comment: I actually saw that on a website last night. Perhaps post one of these domains here so people can see.

Comment: I've edited the post to include a link.

Comment: No problems here, win7 x64 chrome 23.0.1271.97 m. I did, as I said before, see a website with that issue last night, on my home machine, win 8. I'll check later if the page displays that error at home. Additionally, what's your system running?

Comment: No problems on Chrome 26.0.1383.0 on Linux or 25.0.1364.152 on Windows 7.

Comment: Sorry to bring up an old thread... This is happening to me too. I'm using Chrome 34 on Windows 8.1 Pro. So long, and Google hasn't found a fix?

Comment: Related to CSS programming which is best suited on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you shared a link, but in lieu of actually inspecting the problem I can offer the following:

Check the `line-height` css property of the element and be sure that it is enough to accommodate the text, as well as seeing if the element has `overflow: hidden` set. If it is an `inline-block` element, check the `vertical-align` property as well as `height` and `max-height`.

It looks like an @font-face font, which may be the cause. Try switching it to another font-family and see if the problem persists. Use Chrome's inspector tool to inspect the layout of the element and see if its bounding box is indeed smaller that it needs to be or if it is a bug in chrome.

Comment: It is the Oswald font from Google Web Fonts. Link: http://peartree.azurewebsites.net/. Also, after a bit of investigation, it only happens with bold fonts.

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with the bold variant of the font for me, when looking at GWF page, it appears cut too. Font change.